# Elasticsearch is matching substrings when it shouldn't be

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

This is the get request I am running:

```
curl -XGET https://search-mycluster-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/test/_search? -d '
{ "size": 1,
     "_source": ["url"],
    "query" :
    { "match": { "circular": "NC-xx-xxxx-y"} }

}
'
```

It is working correctly, and if I change the circular from "NC-xx-xxxx-y" to "doesntwork" then no results will be returned as expected. If I change it to "NC" (a substring of the original) then the results for "NC-xx-xxxx-y" appear. Even if I make the circular "NC-xx-xxxx-ya" the results for "NC-xx-xxxx-y". I only want the query to work if the circular is exactly "NC-xx-xxxx-y". Any ideas how to change this query?

Here is my mapping:

```
{
   "test" : {
      "mappings" : {
         "files" : {
            "properties" : {
               "submitted_by" : {
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "type" : "text"
               },
               "effective_date" : {
                  "type" : "date",
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "date"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "date_filed" : {
                  "type" : "date",
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "date"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "date" : {
                  "fields" : {
                     "keyword" : {
                        "ignore_above" : 256,
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "type" : "text"
               },
               "form" : {
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "type" : "text"
               },
               "topic" : {
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "type" : "text"
               },
               "circular" : {
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "type" : "text"
               },
               "profit_center" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "url" : {
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "type" : "text"
               },
               "circular_link" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                     "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 256
                     }
                  }
               },
               "subject" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "form_title" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "state" : {
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "type" : "text"
               },
               "lob" : {
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "type" : "text"
               },
               "contractor" : {
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "type" : "text"
               },
               "link_rate_form" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "product_filing" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "status" : {
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "type" : "text"
               },
               "date_entered" : {
                  "type" : "date",
                  "fields" : {
                     "raw" : {
                        "type" : "date"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show your mapping.

Comment: mapping added above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the standard analyser on indexing and on search, so your search term "NC-xx-xxxx-y" gets destructed to ["nc","xx","xxxx","y]. If you want exact matches you can use the term query. If it will be used in a filter query, it should be a little bit faster.

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "term": { "circular.raw" : "NC-xx-xxxx-y" } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Added .raw to circular to search for keyword.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/term-vs-full-text.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: Please add .raw to circular to search in the keyword field. The previous query doesn't work, because the text field is analyzed, too.